# How to check out current item in Nintex reusable site collection workflow SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, nintex

I am trying to create a site collection reusable workflow in Nintex. I have requirement to check out document using workflow. So I add check out item action, and open it to configure it. It has two empty fields. Please see below image for reference:

[image: Nintex check-out action] 
[image: Nintex check-out action check out from empty field]
[image: Nintex check-out action where empty field]

I know Nintex is 3rd party tool, I have also send my query to them but their response was as below:

> Thank you for your question.
>   When using a Reusable Site collection Workflow the workflow can be run on both Libraries and Lists.
>   When you use the Check Out action on a List the configurable arguments are different from when you run them on a Library.
>   Create a list and a library workflow and drag the Check Out action into it and you will see what I mean.
>
> Because List workflows do not allow Check Out of the current item
>   option this option cannot be available on a site/site collection
>   workflow

If anyone has same issue, please tell me  how can I configure current item to check out?

Comment: I think the answer from Nintex were pretty straight forward as it is exactly how SharePoint works. Simply, you can't check out a list item nor a document attached to a list item. This should only be possible on a document library. If this is the case and it does not work then i don't know why. Enabled versioning on the library and try again?

Comment: I am trying to checkout item in document library and have enabled versioning but nothing changes. Any other option?

Comment: Try in another site collection just to determine if there is possible in another site and might be some problem with nintex or else. Is all Nintex features activated?